# validation check for decimal value

Tags: excel, vba

How to validate a excel cell with decimal value using VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub main()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 8
    If Fix(Cells(i, 1)) <> Cells(i, 1) Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Assume we have the following data:

[image]

Result:

[image]